# Gradle include a 3rd party dependency in my project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have this project: https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook/ and people who want to use it must manually add a 3rd party dependency to their build.gradle file. (https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook/wiki/3.-Setup-gdx-facebook)

Like this:

```
compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-android:1.0.0"
compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0" //3rd party project
```

What I want is only this line:

```
compile "de.tomgrill.gdxfacebook:gdx-facebook-android:1.0.0"
```

(1) So the 3rd party project (android-sdk) will be automatically be fetched via gradle when someone ads the dependency (gdx-facebook) to his build.gradle.

or

(2) How do I include the 3rd party project into my project so that it will be automatically compiled/delivered with my project when I publish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module `gdx-facebook-android` just add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0" 
}
```

In this way the [pom file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/tomgrill/gdxfacebook/gdx-facebook-android/1.0.0/gdx-facebook-android-1.0.0.pom) will contain the dependency (as the current gdx-facebook-core module)